# Laravel delete method not working with vuejs

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to complete a CRUD application with Vuejs and Laravel. Right now I can add an article but cannot delete and I ssee this error in my console:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

The html inside the template is like the following:

```
<div class="card card-body"v-for="article in articles" :key="article.id">

    <h3>{{ article.title }}</h3>
    <p>{{ article.body }}</p>
    <button @click="deleteArticle(article.id)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>

</div>
```

Then inside the script I have this:

How can I make the delete work?

```
<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                articles: [],
                article: {
                    id: '',
                    title: '',
                    body: ''
                }, 
                article_id: '',
                pagination: {},
                edit: false
            }
        },
        created(){
            this.fetchAllArticles();
        },
        methods: {
            fetchAllArticles(){ 
                fetch('/api/articles').then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
                    this.articles = res.data;
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
            },
            deleteArticle(id){

                if(confirm('Are you sure?')){
                    fetch('api/article/${id}', {
                        method: 'delete'
                    })
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        alert('Article removed');
                        this.fetchAllArticles();
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err));
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

If I type my url for the delete method I can view the data as you can see in the image:
[image]

My delete controller looks like this:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    // Get article
    $article = Article::findOrFail($id);

    if($article->delete()) {
        return new ArticleResource($article);
    }    
}
```

From the netwok in the browser I see this:
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, your json isn't properly formatted. Can you show us the output coming from the server?

Comment: And is the API address correct ? Never used it this way. In my case I do : `'api/article/' + id`

Comment: If I type my url for the single record http://larticles.local/api/article/1 I can see the json.

Comment: There is not space between the two attributes `class="card card-body"v-for="article in articles"`. Add a space before `v-for`.

Comment: @SrAxi I just noticed that and edited, but its definetely not the issue because I just tried now.

Comment: could you share us your delete controller?

Comment: @Sebastien D I just edited my question and added the delete controller

Comment: I don't get the use of `if($article->delete()) {
        return new ArticleResource($article);
    }   `

Comment: Check your network tab for the response when you delete from the code itself. I think you're getting an error somewhere.

Comment: I will udate my question now with the error on the network. It looks like it is not getting the id number

Comment: From what I see in your console the API address is incorrect, should be `'api/article/' + id`

Comment: @ Sebastien D You were right from the beginning. I added 'api/article/' + id and it works perfectly now. I just needed to clear my browser cache for some reason.
Appreciate the support

Comment: @WosleyAlarico Excellent!

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in your console the API address is incorrect, should be `'api/article/' + id`

Answer (score 0):

> I have never use fetch i love using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), but through googling i found that you have to use not those symbols '' but those `` so:

```
fetch(`api/article/${id}`, {
    method: 'delete'
})
```